# Display all different version documents in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I opened versioning function in a SharePoint library. And I want to display **all different version** of each document in the view. Could you please help me on this?

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just displaying the Versions or should onclick take you to the same version? please have a look at the below code Snippet

```
`using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://Mysite"))
{
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
SPList docs = web.Lists["TestDocLibrary"];
foreach (SPFile file in docs.RootFolder.Files)
{
Console.WriteLine("File Name/URL:- {0} has next version {1}. Version     History:", file.Url, file.UIVersionLabel);
foreach (SPFileVersion v in file.Versions.Cast().Reverse())
{
Console.WriteLine("Version of the file :- {0} time of checkin :- {1} comments while checking in:- '{2}'", v.VersionLabel, v.Created, v.CheckInComment);
}
}
}
}`
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! But I used Sandbox Solution. I had gave up this question. Anyway, thank you!